# When i tried to export the customer i got this error Undefined offset: 0 in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer, export, data-provider

I tried to export the customer from the magento i caught the error i didn't got any solution to resolve it.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /var/www/html/development/amt/vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/DataProvider/Document.php
>   on line 171

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the line mentioned in the error message, the issue seems to be with a non-existent website ID.

Looking at the customer records I realized we had some accounts not associated with any website. These were migrated from Magento 1. Maybe something went wrong during the migration or we made an error when creating these accounts in Magento 1.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

My solution was to simply delete these customer accounts, as they were test accounts anyway.

Afterwards I was able to successfully export all customer records.